# How to utilise apple's "suggested App" function

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I've developed an app for my Organisation, and I would like it to come up as a "suggested App" when people enter my organisations building, similar to the Starbucks app demonstrated an WWDC.

Could someone point me in the right direction to locate any development notes on implementing this feature, and setting up the required hardware?

I've gone through and watched the WWDC videos on Location notifications and Taking Core Locations indoors, but still am a bit unsure as to using this information to make my app appear as a suggested app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I watched the same WWDC sessions as you and read the documentation and I haven't found a clear answer. You have already an organisation and you should try to sign up for indoor positioning and see what you can to with that. 
https://mapsconnect.apple.com

Maybe if you sign up to that program, then you are able to add you app to the suggested apps function. This is only my idea, not 100% confirmed right now.